# How to create class dynamically or on runtime in NetBeans

Tags: java

I took input(scenario) from user and tokenize the class name , attributes and methods out of it.I want to create class with that data.How can i do that in NetBeans.

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Do you want to create the source or class file?